# Optimizing tagged unions in C

Tags: c, unions

I'm using [tagged unions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) in a personal project. As an example, this is the type of code I use:

```
struct data_unit {
  enum {
    d_A, d_B, d_C
  } dtype;
  union {
    char a;
    int b;
    double c;
  } data;
};

void print_data(data_unit du) {
  switch (du.dtype) {
    case d_A: {
      printf("%c", du.data.a);
      break;
    }
    case d_B: {
      printf("%d", du.data.b);
      break;
    }
    case d_C: {
      printf("%lf", du.data.c);
      break;
    }
    default:
      break;
  }
  return;
};
```

Is there more efficient way to implement `print_data`, one without manually checking each case of `dtype`? If C allowed lists of types, I would just iterate through it using the `enum`, but that isn't an available utility. I need a general way to do this, as I plan on adding a lot of data types to the union.

Is this possible to do? If not, what would a better strategy be for me in this context?

Comment: dtype will end up being an int behind the scenes, so you can compare it like `du.dtype == 1`. Then, you could make an array of format specifiers... `format_table[du.dtype]` Or something. I'll have to spool up my VM.

Comment: Efficient how? In terms of execution time? In that case, the `switch` shouldn't take longer with more types because the compiler can implement it with a lookup table.

Comment: @Blacksilver my main issue isn't the formatting text, it's manually having to type `du.data.type` over and over. It feels like something that can be automated and generalized.

Comment: @interjay I mean efficient in terms of not retyping the same code over and over.

Comment: @user189728 Yeah, my hope is to end up with like one or two statements, then you just have to fill out an array somewhere with how to print any new data types. Hold on to your hat.

Comment: [I think this will work, but I'm not sure.](https://pastebin.com/6PdGzw3c)

Comment: @Blacksilver that doesn't really solve my problem, but that's a feature of unions I wasn't aware of

Comment: Also, turns out it's wrong. Still working on it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168469/discussion-between-user189728-and-blacksilver).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the fact that a pointer to a struct-object may be treated as a pointer to its first member. Hence, when exchanging `dtype` and `data`, you could access all members in some generic way:

```
struct data_unit {
    union {
        char a;
        int b;
        double c;
    } data;
    enum {
        d_A, d_B, d_C
    } dtype;
};

typedef void (print_data_unit) (struct data_unit *du);

void print_data_unit_char(struct data_unit *du) {
    printf("%c\n", *((char*)(du)));
}
void print_data_unit_double(struct data_unit *du) {
    printf("%lf\n", *((double*)(du)));
}
void print_data_unit_int(struct data_unit *du) {
    printf("%d\n", *((int*)(du)));
}

static print_data_unit* functions[3] = { print_data_unit_char, print_data_unit_int, print_data_unit_double };

void print_data(struct data_unit du) {
    functions[du.dtype](&du);
}

int main() {

    struct data_unit du;

    du.dtype = 0;
    du.data.a = 'c';
    print_data(du);

    du.dtype = 1;
    du.data.b = 100;
    print_data(du);

    du.dtype = 2;
    du.data.c = 200.55;
    print_data(du);
}
```

Comment: I know this might be having my cake and eating it too, but is there any way to do this in such a way that if I was to add more data types to the union, I wouldn't have to add more functions? (Ignoring the format strings)

Comment: No, you'll need a specific function for each specific data type; yet at least you do not need a specific function for each member, as you can "generically" access them without knowing their respective "name"; you just need the type in order to know how to properly access/cast it.

Comment: Conversion of `struct data_unit *du` to `(double*)` is UB, yet rarely a _bad_ UB.  `du->data.c` does not have this trouble incurred by `*((double*)(du))`.

Comment: There's no point to the pointer casting when you can simply access the correct member by name in each function. But I don't really see how this method is better than a `switch` - it is even more verbose, and error-prone.